# How to get the Solr Master Slave replication status using Solrj

Tags: solr, solrj

I am trying to retrieve the Solr Master Slave replication status using SolrJ. I have not been able to find how to get this using the Core Admin calls or set the request handler to the Replication handler.

Or perhaps I could call this HTTP API call using SolrJ

```
http://host:port/solr/core_name/replication?command=indexversion
```

But how to that is something that escapes me currently.

Looking for pointers in this direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case this helps someone, what I did to get the data I needed was

```
    SolrClient solrServer = new HttpSolrClient.Builder("http://localhost:8983/solr/" + coreName).build();
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.setRequestHandler("/replication");
    query.set("command", "indexversion");
    query.set("wt", "json");
    query.set("indent", "true");

    //fire the solr query
    QueryResponse response = solrServer.query(query);

    //get the indexversion value from response
    String indexVersion = 
    response.getResponse().get("indexversion").toString();
```